# Upgrade Python modules at Bluemix, to get out of the error (No trigger by the name “interval” was found)

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, ibm-cloud

I am using the ipython of apache spark service at bluemix. I need to reinstall setuptools, but I can't enter password for sudo. How can I proceed to make it work ( the goal is to fulfil the following actually )

https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/77/lookuperror-no-trigger-by-the-name

Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 2):

You do not have root permissions with this service, so you cannot install anything at the system level and you cannot run sudo. If you want to install apscheduler, then run pip with the '--user' arg so that it installs local to your tenant.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: IBM has deployed new software levels last week. If you create a new Apache Spark service on Bluemix, your environment won't include the offending version of setuptools anymore.

original answer:

As Randy pointed out, you cannot reinstall setuptools. Until IBM upgrades that package, use the workaround mentioned in the issue you linked:

"In the meantime, you can instantiate the triggers manually"
https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/77/lookuperror-no-trigger-by-the-name#comment-14180022

The author of apscheduler apparently added a check for the version of setuptools. You'll have to use an older version of apscheduler without that check.